# Add media type of links created by Telerik StyleSheetRegistrar

Tags: telerik, telerik-mvc

Is it possible to set the media attribute on a link tag using the Telerik MVC Extensions `StyleSheetRegistrar` method?

```
<%= Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar()
    .DefaultGroup(group => group
        .Add("telerik.common.css")
        .Add("telerik." + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Telerik Theme"].ToLower() + ".min.css"))
%>
```

I want to add `media="screen,handheld"` to all the stylesheet links created by the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, this is not currently possible. You can either modify the source code or use vanilla `<link />` tags to register the CSS files. You don't seem to be using compression or combination so using `<link />` tags seems feasible.

Comment: thanks for the speedy response.

is support planned for this in the near future?

Comment: I am not really sure. It is not clear where the media should be specify - at group level or at asset level. If at group level - the implementation is trivial. If at asset level - we have to make sure we handle compression and combination properly as then we output only one <link /> tag.

Comment: i think group level, then you just have one combined stylesheet for each type of media

Answer (score 2):

It actually is possible using a Replace:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar()
                      .DefaultGroup(group => group
                      .Add("default.css")
                      .Combined(true).Compress(true))
                      .ToHtmlString().Replace(">", " media=\"all\">"))
```